# Project-To-Project Reference In VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I have a solution containing 2 C++ static library projects. Both projects are contained in the same directory as the solution and their output path's are both the debug folder in the solution directory.

So I have project A and project B. I want project B to reference project A as if it was a static lib file included in the linker settings. So I went into project B's properties and added project A as a reference, although when I look in the class view I can't see project A as a project B reference??

Project A still compiles fine, but if I need to do anything else to access the classes I have in project A from project B (as if I was adding it through the linker section I would also have to define the location for the headers - is this neccessary when adding a project-to-project reference?)

Comment: "Project reference" is a managed code concept.  Works well in a C++/CLI project, an assembly contains metadata with full class declarations.  Not in native C++, a .lib cannot be reversed back.  Class View only knows about *compiled* code, not linked libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the include path for your source folder to the "Addtional Include Directories" under "Project Properties -> Configuration Propertties -> C/C++ -> General"?

Comment: sorry - i dont exactly understand what you're asking.. could you elaborate a little

Comment: Are you sharing the same folder for where your source files are? As in, are your .h/.cpp files from Project B in the same folder as your .h/.cpp files from Project A? If they are not, then in order to use those classes you will still need to be able to view the header files, in which case you will need to include the source folder for project A in project B.